# Redirect WordPress Header Logo To Specific URL

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to redirect the header logo to a specific URL as well. I came across this site during my research. Please take a look at the following code and let me know exactly what modifications needs to be made to accomplish this. Thanks in advance.

```
<h1 class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
     <a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr(get_bloginfo('name', 'display')); ?>" rel="home">
         <?php echo $logo; ?>
     </a>
</h1>
```

Thanks,

Jon

Comment: What do you mean by  "redirect the header logo" as in when you click the link ?

Comment: Yes, sorry.  When the header logo at the top left of the page is clicked, I would like it to redirect to a specific URL other than where it currently redirects to.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>` and replace it with your URL like so:

```
<h1 class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
     <a href="https://example.net" title="<?php echo esc_attr(get_bloginfo('name', 'display')); ?>" rel="home">
         <?php echo $logo; ?>
     </a>
</h1>
```

Comment: I replaced that code with my URL per your previous instructions, but still not redirecting to the specified URL.  Any suggestions?  Thanks so much for your prompt response.  I wasn't sure how to add the code to this comment.

Comment: Post your code as an edit to the original question, please.